# Delete, MassDelete, Save events for Product reviews

Tags: magento-2.1, review, product-review

I am building an extension related to product reviews in magento 2 but I couldn't find any related article/question to product reviews observers. 
I went through different articles which states all/partial events of magento 2. Here are some of the links but they don't contain these events:

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-events.html

https://cyrillschumacher.com/magento2-list-of-all-dispatched-events/

Can anyone tell me exact event names for **review save**, **review delete**, **reviews mass delete** for **backend** and also **review save** event for frontend?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Magento2 have default events for all ResourceModels

The ones you need should be

1. `review_save_commit_after`
2. `review_delete_commit_after`

check out the other default events in the class `\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel`